# C++ linker - How can g++ pick up ld

Tags: c++, linker

I am new to C++ compiler. I wonder how can I change **some setting of g++** to call the right **ld** version that I want.

For exmaple, I tried:

**g++ "some shared libraries and files"**

then /usr/bin/ld will be called internally. What should I do to make g++ call ***/home/alex/binutils-2.25/bin/ld*** instead ?

Thank you so much.

Alex

Comment: @juanchopanza hey I'm sorry but that's not a duplicate he wants to call another ld (some ideas here: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/98185-how-specify-ld-when-make-binary-using-gplusplus.html)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oops! Re-opened.

Comment: In short: compile source files separately with `g++ -c`, then link all the stuff together as a separate stage. Search for "g++ compile only", "makefiles"

Comment: XY problem? What is tje goal of this exercise?

Answer (score 4):

Not the best idea in general, because these two are tightly integrated and there is a reason GCC has its own search paths with the appropriate tools for that particular build of GCC, so it's better to switch toolchain as a whole.

Anyway, the link provided by Jean-François Fabre is right in its `-B` parameter suggestion and not so right about `PATH` environment variable, because `PATH` is only searched when there is no match in GCCs internal paths, and usually there is something there.

You can take a look at the current paths used by GCC to find its components with `g++ -print-search-dirs`, you're interested in `programs`. It's also easy to check where exactly your compiler finds `ld` (or any other component) with `g++ -print-prog-name=ld`, it also allows to check how `-B` affects the result, like:

```
$ g++ -print-prog-name=ld
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld
$ g++ -B/home/rik/bin -print-prog-name=ld
/home/rik/bin/ld
```

Compare that to

```
$ PATH=/home/rik/bin:$PATH g++ -print-prog-name=ld
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld
```

---

[edit]

And BTW, even this won't help you if your GCC was specifically configured using `--with-ld` option (not the usual way, but), that overrides all other paths.